# js: difference between using + and += to add a space to each element in a 'for' loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 let sentence = ["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "Per"] 
            
    for (i=0; i<sentence.length; i++){
        sentence[i] + " "
        console.log(sentence)
    }
```

if i use `+ " "` to add a space, no space is added to each element in the array and console prints out `5["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "Per"]`

however, if i use `+= " "`, a space is added to each element and console prints out
`1["Hello ", "my", "name", "is", "Per"] 2["Hello ", "my ", "name" "is", "Per"] 3["Hello ", "my ", "name ", "is", "Per"] 4["Hello ", "my ", "name ", "is ", "Per"] 5["Hello ", "my ", "name ", "is ", "Per "]`

could someone explain the logic behind why using `+ " "` doesn't add a space to each element?

Answer (score 1):

The expression `x + y` evaluates to the two variables concatenated together. By itself this is useless as you aren't doing anything with the new value. For it to be useful you need to assign it to a variable, pass it to a function, return it, etc.

The expression `x += y` evaluates to the two variables concatenated together **but also assigns the result to `x`**.

Answer (score 1):

`sentence[i] + " "` returns a new string with the space concatenated. If you want to use this string, you need to assign it to something or pass it as a parameter to a function. For instance, to change the value of the array element, you can write:

```
sentence[i] = sentence[i] + " ";
```

The `+=` operator is a shortcut for assigning the result of the addition back to the same location. So the above is equivalent to

```
sentence[i] += " ";
```

Answer (score 0):

- `+` is just an operation (concatenation in your case), so if you do `sentence[i] + " "` but don't assign the result to a variable, the result is lost. [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#arithmetic_operators)
- `+=` is an operation and assignment, ie the result of the concatenation is assigned back to the original value. Thus `sentence[i] += " "` is equivalent to `sentence[i] = sentence[i] + " "`  [(docs)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment)